# ruby on rails equivalent statement of find_by_sql

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

What will be the equivalent find statement of the following below ?

```
@mostviews = Post.find_by_sql("select posts.id,posts.title from posts inner join countpages on countpages.post_id = posts.id order by countpages.counts desc limit 5")


@temp = Post.find_by_sql("SELECT posts.id,posts.title, comment_count.count FROM posts INNER JOIN (SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) AS count FROM comments GROUP BY post_id) AS comment_count ON comment_count.post_id = posts.id  ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 5;")
```

Is it possible to get the same result using find or where function ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Post.select("posts.id, posts.title").joins(:countpage).order("countpages.counts desc").limit(5)
```

This assumes countpage is an association. Otherwise, you can be more explicit in the joins ("INNER JOIN...")

Comment: I got error, for this , @mostviews = Post.select("posts.id, posts.title").joins(:countpages).order("countpages.counts desc").limit(5)  ,  ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError in Posts#index

Showing myproject/app/views/posts/_rightsidediv.html.erb where line #55 raised:

Association named 'countpages' was not found; perhaps you misspelled it?  and this is the line => <% mostviews.each do |t| %>

Comment: That's because countpages isn't an association for you.

You can do 
    .joins("inner join countpages on countpages.post_id = posts.id") instead of .joins(:countpage)

Comment: Thank you. I have added another find_by_sql statement in original question. Can you please post the equivalent statement of that too?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a new question.